# Hot to use CSS3 filter in Mozilla?

Tags: html, css, svg

So it seems that there is [no simple use of `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#Browser_compatibility) in current versions of Firefox.

However, the documentation proposes a workaround using `filter: url('something')`. The problem is that documentation is *quite* uncler on that topic and it sounds and appears like a very wild magic.

They explain [`blur()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter#blur%28%29) with this XML/SVG:

```
<svg height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <filter id="svgBlur" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"/>
  </filter>
</svg>
```

But all I have found is this in the page code:

```
<image height="161px" width="212px" y="5%" x="5%" filter="url(#svgBlur)" xlink:href="/files/3710/Test_Form_2.jpeg">
```

Strange `xlink:href` thingy aside, how does `#svgBlur` specify a file location? I tried to append it to the url but nothing interesting happened...

So:

1. How does linking without path work?
2. Can I include the filter rules in the CSS file? Can I somehow *define* them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In firefox, you can't have CSS filters for your elements, so you're going to have to use pure SVG to add filters to your images. The `url(#svgBlur)` syntax is simply SVG syntax for applying filters to your elements. Have a look at this code:

```
<svg id="img3" viewBox="0 0 233 176">
  <filter id="svgBlur" x="-5%" y="-5%" width="110%" height="110%">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="5"></feGaussianBlur>
  </filter>
  <image xlink:href="/files/3710/Test_Form_2.jpeg" filter="url(#svgBlur)" x="5%" y="5%" width="212px" height="161px"></image>
</svg>
```

What that `filter=""` attribute does is take the filter defined in the `<filter>` element with `id="svgBlur"`. In this case, it's a Gaussian Blur filter. The syntax `url(#svgBlur)` is used, because elements that have a defined `id` attribute will act as an anchor on the page, so referring to the `#svgBlur` on that page will basically link to the element that has that `id` attribute, which is a `<filter>` in this case.

The reason you use `<image>` instead of `<img>` and `xlink:href` instead of `href` is because that's the required syntax in SVG. You also need to define the `xlink` namespace when you're using links in an `example.svg` file.